# Please explain former High Court of Australia Justice Kenneth Hayne's jape?

Tags: australia, judge

The questioner is Oxford Law Prof. [Joshua Getzler](https://www.law.ox.ac.uk/people/joshua-getzler). Former High Court of Australia Justice Kenneth Hayne answers at [1:08:28](https://youtu.be/ivjp2nNb2A0?t=4108). They're both Australian.

> Joshua my answer is very simple. If you could let
> me have something in publishable form, my
> time for final report is 1st February
> next year. I'd be much obliged.

Undoubtedly Hayne is [joshing](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=josh)! Because sitting next to Hayne, Lord Mance —  former Deputy UKSC President  — guffaws, and thumps the table with his hand!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Justice Hayne was acting as a Royal Commissioner on [banking misconduct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Commission_into_Misconduct_in_the_Banking,_Superannuation_and_Financial_Services_Industry) and the issue being discussed was in the scope of the RC. The joke (as such) was he was asking for someone to write the final report for him.